# Create intraday chart with R using chartSeries, candleChart, or barChart?

Tags: r, charts

Can chartSeries, candleChart, or barChart be used to create an intraday chart in R?

chartSeries, candleChart, and barChart are part of the quantmod package for R.

Comment: Please provide some sample data, otherwise there might be no help at all.

Answer (score 14):

First we need some example intraday trading data, which you can get for free from [a variety of sites](https://www.quantshare.com/sa-426-6-ways-to-download-free-intraday-and-tick-data-for-the-us-stock-market) including [Google's Undocumented Finance API](http://www.networkerror.org/component/content/article/1-technical-wootness/44-googles-undocumented-finance-api.html).

### Get some example data (hourly intervals)

```
query_addr <- 'https://www.google.com/finance/getprices'
stock_symb <- 'GOOG'
stock_exch <- 'NASD'
intvl_size <- 60*60 # 1 hr interval (in seconds) -- use 24*this for daily
period_len <- '90d'
output_fmt <- 'd,o,h,l,c,v' # date, open, high, low, close, volume

library(httr)
resp <- 
  POST(url = query_addr, 
       query = list(q = stock_symb, 
                    x = stock_exch, 
                    i = intvl_size, 
                    p = period_len,
                    f = output_fmt) )

df <- 
  read.csv(text = content(resp),
           skip = 7,
           header = FALSE,
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# we need a function to munge the date convention used by google finance API
g_fin_date <- function(dstr, intvl_size){
  unix_dates <- numeric(length(dstr))
  date_is_unix <- grepl('^a',dstr)
  unix_dates[date_is_unix] <- as.numeric(sub('^a','',dstr[date_is_unix]))
  for(i in 2L:length(dstr)){
    if(!date_is_unix[i]){
      unix_dates[i] <- unix_dates[i-1] + intvl_size
    }
  }
  return(as.POSIXct(unix_dates,origin="1970-01-01",tz="GMT" ))
}

# see header of resp text for column order
names(df) <- c('close_date','Close','High','Low','Open','Volume') 
df[,'close_date'] <- g_fin_date(df[,'close_date'], intvl_size=intvl_size)
```

Here I have just chosen hourly open (i.e. beginning price), high, low, close (i.e. ending price)-- but you can specify a finer level of detail if you desire -- it will still roll up to a larger period with `quantmod::to.period()`.

### Make an `xts`

Once we have a data frame (such as you might obtain from an API or flat file) then you need to convert the data to `xts`.  Note that for `xts` the timestamp must be the row name (and can be dropped from the columns).

```
library(xts)
rownames(df) <- df$close_date
df$close_date <- NULL
```

### Convert to OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close) using `xts`

This is straightforward aggregation -- see `?to.period`

```
GOOG <- to.hourly(as.xts(df)) # for daily use to.daily(as.xts(df))
```

More chart examples available [at quantmod.com](https://www.quantmod.com/examples/charting/).

### Make some charts using `quantmod`

There are great charts already built into `quantmod`, including the ones you mentioned.

```
library(quantmod)
chartSeries(GOOG)
barChart(GOOG, theme='white.mono',bar.type='hlc')
candleChart(GOOG,multi.col=TRUE,theme='white')
```

### Enjoy your charts

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't know about the down vote.  I'll offer an observation however that OP asked for intraday charts.  The solution offered above is for daily charts owing both to the choice of interval size in the query, and in the application of the daily aggregation function.  The charting functions have no problem with the intraday periods.

Comment: @mrbcuda thanks for the feedback.  I thought that because these charts show the intraday high and low that was what OP wanted.  I will use a shorter period.  I am not in finance so not sure what the term means.

Answer (score 0):

Me: "I'll take intra-day time series charts in `R` for 100 Alex!" :D

Alex: "THIS popular format for financial time series can be used by `quantmod` functions `chartSeries`, `candleChart`, and `barChart` to create intraday charts in `R`"

Me: "What is an `xts` object, indexed by data/time stamp, containing prices for the Open, High, Low, and Close?

Alex: "Right you are!"